# Best practices for custom AJAX in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

For standard forms, I know you can use `remote: true` to have the form submitted via AJAX. But what about situations where you don't have a standard form? For example, I have an SVG map of the US. When the user clicks on a state (i.e. a `<path>` element), it triggers an AJAX request so that my app can store a vote for that state in the database. I have this working fine by simply binding the `click` event to the `path` element and then using the standard jQuery `$.ajax()` method. However, I'm not sure if there is a different, more "standard" way of triggering AJAX requests through non-form interactions.

I'm also not sure what the best practice is for how the Rails controller should respond to this request. For now, I simply have it responding with:

```
if vote.save
    render json: {success: true}
else
    render json: {success: false, data: vote.errors}
end
```

I then check the value of `success` in my `$.ajax` success callback and handle the case of `false` there.

I'm very new to Rails and simply made all this up on my own. Is this hacky? Are there different, standardized ways for sending & responding to AJAX requests in a situation like this that doesn't involve a form?

Comment: you can't get much more standard than jquery :) As for the controller code - it's fine. But some people think it's better to use specialized json builders, like jbuilder, rabl or active_model_serializers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did for your ajax json request is reasonable and you will find that structure in a lot of rails code that specifically has to communicate with a javascript client that requires json

However, you should also note that we usually prefer js over json (given the choice) as then we can leverage jquery-ujs as you mentioned in your question (remote: true)